# I can't upgrade pip on my raspberry pi

Tags: python, pip

I want to install simpleaudio but  can't upgrade or install anything with pip, here's what it gives me:

```
Downloading/unpacking pip from             https://pypi.python.org/packages/9c/32/004ce0852e0a127f07f358b715015763273799b    d798956fa930814b60f39/pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=0570520434c5b600d89ec95393b2650b
  Downloading pip-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB): 1.2MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 1.5.6
    Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
  Can't roll back pip; was not uninstalled
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 295, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1436, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 672, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 902, in move_wheel_files
    pycompile=self.pycompile,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 214, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 204, in clobber
    os.makedirs(destdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2.dist-info'

Storing debug log for failure in /home/pi/.pip/pip.log
```

I'm using Rasbian with NOOBS if that help figuring this out. I've just started studying programming so I have no clue what I need to do since using the guides results to above, so please explain this to an idiot.

Comment: Did you try running your commands with `sudo` or _as root_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` fails to access some system paths and shows clearly that the user used to run `pip` *does not have enough privileges* to access them.

To solve this, try to run these commands as root using `sudo`:

```
sudo pip <options>
```

Otherwise, if you don't have *sudo* installed (this is almost impossible) or if you're just curious and know the *root*'s password, simply log in as root and execute your commands without `sudo`:

```
su # or su root
# type the root's password

pip <options>
```

If you use this option, *don't forget to log out after you've installed everything!*